# How to get the story name programmatically

Tags: jbehave

I am running multiple jbehave test files at once, and I need to get the story name of each file and save it.
I want this to be done on each step so I could know how many times a specific story is calling a specific step.
Is this doable, and if yes how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using Meta parameter as shown in the JBehave website:

[JBehave Meta parametrisation](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-parametrisation.html)

In your case, you'd need to set a storyName parameter in each story and then accept it in your step methods.